# Syntax error near $$DELIMITER

Tags: mysql

i'm getting an error while creating a stored procedure, where it says that i have a syntax error, but i can't find where it is...

MySql Error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '$$DELIMITER
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE 'entradas_sai'(IN ID_VEICULO VARCHAR(45), OUT' at
>   line 1

Here is the code related to the topic:

```
$$DELIMITER

CREATE PROCEDURE 'entradas_sai'(
IN ID_VEICULO VARCHAR(45), OUT retcode INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE '_rollback' BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET '_rollback' = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO SAIDAS(data, hora) VALUES(CURDATE("yyyy-MM-dd"),CURTIME("hh:mm:ss))
    UPDATE ENTRADAS(SAI) WITH VALUES(@SAI)
    IF '_rollback' THEN
        SET retcode = 0;
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        SET retcode = 1;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a screenshot of my MySqlWB:

[image: MySql WorkBench]

EDIT:
Here is the log:

```
>Executing:
>USE `portaria`;
>DROP unknown IF EXISTS `unknown_SYNTAX_ERROR`;
>
>DELIMITER $$
>USE `portaria`$$
>DELIMITER $$
>
>CREATE PROCEDURE 'entradas_sai'(
>IN ID_VEICULO VARCHAR(45), OUT retcode INT)
>BEGIN
>    DECLARE '_rollback' BOOL DEFAULT 0;
>    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET '_rollback' = 1;
>    START TRANSACTION;
>    INSERT INTO SAIDAS(data, hora) VALUES(date(now()) ,time(now()))
>    UPDATE ENTRADAS(SAI) WITH VALUES(@SAI)
>    IF '_rollback' THEN
>        SET retcode = 0;
>        ROLLBACK;
>    ELSE
>        SET retcode = 1;
>        COMMIT;
>    END IF;
>END$$
>
>DELIMITER ;$$
>
>DELIMITER ;
>
>ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that >corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near >'unknown IF EXISTS `unknown_SYNTAX_ERROR`' at line 1
>SQL Statement:
>DROP unknown IF EXISTS `unknown_SYNTAX_ERROR`
```

Here i got a scenarion of what i want my procedure to do...

> I have a table called "Entradas" and one called "Saidas". Both have
>   the column "data" and "hora". With that in mind, since the "data" and
>   "hora column of "entradas" mean that a car joined at that date and
>   time, and the values from the columns "data" and "hora" of "saidas"
>   are mean to be inserted as i click a button, inserting the current
>   date and time. I'm requesting a sql syntax that could insert the
>   values "data" and "hora" into the table "saidas" and update a value of
>   "entradas" called "sai" which is equal to 0 and i want it to change to
>   1 on button press... Any sugestion?

Comment: Read the error again. It always says the exact spot in code.

Comment: i know where it is, but what's wrong with the syntax? :o i cannot find the actual error...

Comment: How about the leading `$$` characters that the error complaints about? The command is called [delimiter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html#idm140674408146480), not `$$delimiter`. You even use it correctly some lines later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what was wrong, and it wasn't only about "DELIMITER" but with a couple things more...

Here is the fixed code:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE entradas_sai (
IN ID_VEICULO VARCHAR(45), OUT retcode INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _rollback BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET _rollback = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO SAIDAS(data, hora) VALUES(date(now()) ,time(now()));
    UPDATE ENTRADAS SET SAI=1;
    IF '_rollback' THEN
        SET retcode = 0;
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        SET retcode = 1;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END $$
```

Steps: Removed the "Delimiter $$" and "Delimiter ;" and then restructured the UPDATE query. That was the main problem, because the syntax wasn't on the spot... Thanks all who tryied to help.

In this case the value of "1" wasn't the value i want... So, i changed it to @sai, which means that the value is given at a button click, which is a increment of the parameter @sai, being equal to 1,2,3,4 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

delimiter symbol (`$$`) come after `DELIMITER` keyword. also use `date(now())` instead `CURDATE("yyyy-MM-dd")` and `time(now())` instead `CURTIME("hh:mm:ss"))` 
Try This

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `entradas_sai`(IN ID_VEICULO VARCHAR(45), OUT retcode INT)
BEGIN
        DECLARE _rollback boolean DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET _rollback = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO SAIDAS(data, hora) VALUES(date(now()) ,time(now()));
        UPDATE ENTRADAS SET SAI = @SAI;
        IF _rollback = 1 THEN
            SET retcode = 0;
            ROLLBACK;
        ELSE
            SET retcode = 1;
            COMMIT;
        END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @Tiago in your edit procedure problem is you are use the single quote in procedure name remove it then your screen shot error go away

Comment: not so much, if i remove the quotes i get more errors than i had before. That's a bigger problem, because the research i did on the internet the fix was to remove the quotes. Apparently it doesn't work...

Comment: after did you change curdate  function ?

Comment: @TiagoTurella in your edited procedure there is so many errors as i seen.

Comment: Any sugestion on how to fix them all? I'm not much into sql,  but since i'm creating a button that requires 2 queries, i had to try it... but i'm having more problems then my 1st attempt :/

Comment: what is the value of @SAI ?

Comment: why you use '_rollback' ? what you want in your procedure can you explain ?

Comment: it is decided on the cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sai", 1)

Comment: Scenario:

I have a table called "Entradas" and one called "Saidas". Both have the column "data" and "hora". With that in mind, since the "data" and "hora column of "entradas" mean that a car joined at that date and time, and the values from the columns "data" and "hora" of "saidas" are mean to be inserted as i click a button, inserting the current date and time. I'm requesting a sql syntax that could insert the values "data" and "hora" into the table "saidas" and update a value of "entradas" called "sai" which is equal to 0 and i want it to change to 1 on button press... Any sugestion?

Comment: I have update your procedure its run succefully in my system plz check

Answer (score 1):

If i'm right, you mistyped `$$DELIMITER`, it should be `DELIMITER $$`

EDIT: after adding the screenshot to the question, i believe you shouldn't quote the procedure name. I have update the code-block, try it again please.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE entradas_sai(
IN ID_VEICULO VARCHAR(45), OUT retcode INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE '_rollback' BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET '_rollback' = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO SAIDAS(data, hora) VALUES(CURDATE("yyyy-MM-dd"),CURTIME("hh:mm:ss"))
    UPDATE ENTRADAS(SAI) WITH VALUES(@SAI)
    IF '_rollback' THEN
        SET retcode = 0;
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        SET retcode = 1;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Fixed that error, but still the same... "error near '$$DELIMITER

CREATE PROCEDURE 'entradas_sai'(IN ID_VEICULO VARCHAR(45), OUT' at line 1"

Comment: @TiagoTurella the error you send, has exact that mistake still in it. Please re-evaluate the error

Comment: i added a screenshot of what it's wrong, the error i got was in visual studio, on mysql wb i dont get the error, just those red waves saying that an error is placed there.

Comment: i will edit my question so the log is here. I think i didn't explained as i wanted.

Comment: have you tried running it as `CREATE PROCEDURE entradas_sai` instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE 'entradas_sai'`

Comment: i believe unknown is a preserved keyword, put single quotes around it

Comment: `DROP 'unknown' IF EXISTS 'nknown_SYNTAX_ERROR';`  instead of `DROP unknown IF EXISTS 'unknown_SYNTAX_ERROR';`